# weblogic 8.1 out of memory

Tags: memory, weblogic8.x

my weblogic 8.1 gives out of memory if i dont click the garbage collector for a long time, i have increased the -Xms512m -Xmx1024m and also the max perm size in setdomainenv.bat, is there any other way also which i have missed i have a 4 GB (3.2 read) system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is in question itself, set the java memory variable to optimum and the perm size also (only if former doesn't helps) and then if the problem persists, actually it should not check whether your system is able to cope with the new set memory for the jvm :)

Answer (score 0):

Your system sounds like it's leaking memory.  You ought to get a profiler to help you figure out where so you can plug the leak.

If you can't do that, another answer would be to bounce the server on a regular basis to reset the JVM.  However, option #1 is greatly preferred.